# Is it possible to generate an own typings.d.ts file from a .js file?

Tags: typescript, angular

I want to use some libraries in angular 2 which are not implemented yet, is it possible to create an own typings file from javascript?

Is there an online generator or something likely?

It will help me out so much! I know this is not the best question on stack but I really need the help from here.

Comment: How would the typings file know, what kind of types the javascript variables have?

Comment: See the accepted answer in the question of my flag. You still have to manually fix the generated type definition file of course. But this will help a lot with getting started.